# How to push different README.md from one working directory to two repositories using git

Tags: git, github

I'd like to push from one working directory to two repositories (Github on WAN and Gitbucket on LAN) using git.

I'd like to make the content to be pushed slightly different.
For example;
I want to make README.md separate.
Also, I do not want to push a file to one repository and push it to the other repository.
What kind of method do you have?

Comment: You will have to create two working directories (two `.git` folder + two .gitignore) and keep moving them into and out of the repo directory. It's a bit tedious. You could have two branches with the changes you wish to have, and use `git submodule` to track them in two different repos. I guess that would work.

Comment: Thank you. I will examine git submodule.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would also recommend having two separate working directories, each with their own remote repo URL as "origin".
Trying to do everything in one repo is error-prone: you will make a mistake at some point, and push the wrong file or content to the wrong remote.

Second, you can do a

- push from your first local repo to your second local repo, and
- add in your second local repo a [`post-receive` hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d166e6afe5f257217836ef24a73764eba390c58d/Documentation/githooks.txt#L309) where you can script the changes you need in said second repo: amend of the `README` content, deletion of a file.
  That same hook, automatically trigger by your push, can itself triggers a push to your second remote repo. With the right content.